# Layouts Dinámicos de paneles en C#

Tags: c#, layout, visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop

Quisiera hacer una aplicación en `C#`, en la cuál puedo añadir paneles que se muevan con el evento `Drag And Drop`. Pero no encuentro la forma que me brinde este rombo simular cuando se mueven las ventanas en `visual studio`. Para un mayor entendimiento adjuntaré el siguiente [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx)

El rombo que busco es similar a este para mover los paneles.
[image: Rombo]

No sé si debo programarlo yo mismo o usar alguna propiedad del `C#`

Comment: Seria bueno que especificaras si es estas utilizando windows forms o wpf.